# How to use mv command to remove unwanted character from multiple files in the same directory

Tags: command-line, centos, mv

I have in a directory some files:

```
agent_datad.bin
_codecs_cn.cpython-34m.so
_Crypto.Cipher._ARC4.so
Crypto.Hash._RIPEMD160.so
...
other files
```

How can I remove the `_` from the beginning of each file that begins with this character ? I only want **the first** `_` removed as some files can have underscore at other position. A one-line command would be awesome.

As a mention, I use CentOS 7 and using `mv` is not mandatory but that's what came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner (the echo shows what the command will do):

```
for name in *; do echo mv ${name} ${name##_} ; done
```

`${name##_}` returns the $name variable without the _ at the beginning of the variable

When you are happy, remove the `echo` from the command.

Good luck!